# Why is javascript enabled by default in the Tor browser?

Tags: anonymity, javascript, tor-browser-bundle

I read that javascript should be disabled in the Tor browser, as it could harm my anonymity. However, Javascript is enabled in Tor default configuration.

- **Why did the developers made the choice to enable Javascript by default?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They weighted the pros and cons, between security and user experience.**

You are right, Javascript makes your browsing unsafe. It allows a website to deanonymize Tor users. [It has been used previously by the FBI, when they seized Freedom Hosting.](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/08/attackers-wield-firefox-exploit-to-uncloak-anonymous-tor-users/) The FBI put a malicious script on their server. When the visitors came and loaded the content, the script was executed client-side. It exploited a 0-day vulnerability in Firefox, making the clients contact, with their public IP, a server controlled by the FBI.

Another reason to disable Javascript is [browser fingerprinting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) Basically, Javascript has access to a lot of parameters which can differ from a computer to another one (browser plugins, language, fonts installed, etc.). [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) provides an interesting test to check whether you can be fully identified using these information.

**However,** Javascript is also a necessary component of the Web. Simply disabling it would break the user experience on most of the websites. [As Tor documentation says,](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBJavaScriptEnabled) it would be an impediment to new users. The developers choose to favor them by activating Javascript in the default configuration. User experience comes first; the users wanting more privacy can still disable Javascript using the NoScript plugin.